# NLA Editor Question

Tags: animation, armature

Can you "edit" a key action within the NLA Editor?  As you can see from the image below, I have six pages in a book that turn perfectly...EXCEPT each page is repeating itself once, resulting in 12 pages!  I only want 6 pages, and I only want to turn ONE PAGE at a time:
[image]

The Blend is here if anyone could please help...I'm desperate to complete this project this week.  Thanks for any help! [.blend](https://jumpshare.com/v/b1c7JC29tCjYLBkKtbgK)

Comment: Hi jmarkt.  I'm not sure what you're intending.  Editing within an action isn't really something the NLA was designed for, but you can select strips and hit 'Tab' and open up the F-Curve editor to Edit the animation there.  I'm not sure I understand your need to repeat things.  Presumably, if you only want 6 page turns, set the 'repeat' field to 0.  But you clearly understand how to do that..

Comment: Thanks, Mike, for the quick reply.  Actually, I really don't understand :>)  I followed a tutorial to get this far, and now I'm trying to modify it to fit my needs.  With a little guidance, I'm sure I can find/set the repeat field, but can only "look around" at this point.  Thanks again for taking the time to help!

Comment: Ok well good on you for getting this far, the NLA usually bewilders people.  Try selecting one of your strips, hit `N` to bring up the properties tab, scroll down until you see Action Clip, find the `repeat` field, and change it to 0.  But I'm unsure this will lead to the desired effect.

Comment: I changed the Repeat value to .001 (min default?), and I still end up with "two Page 2's", "2 Page 3's", etc???

Answer (score -1):

Revisited the issue, and tweaked the "Repeat" field to "1" on the Armatures (rather than the pages), and all is well now.  Thanks again to Mike Belanger for putting me on the right trail!